# iOS - Navigation bar border does not show up immediately when view controller is pushed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I used large title in two subsequent view controllers. When the second view controller is pushed, the nav bar bottom border shows up after a delay. But when I tap on Back button, the nav bar border in the first view controller shows up immediately without any delay. Is there any solution to that issue? Thanks!

Please refer to the screenshots below:

[First Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSaeo.jpg)

[Second Screen (The nav bar border shows up with a delay about 0.5 sec)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwz6p.jpg)

Update: each time I build and run the app, the first time I go to the second view controller, there is NO delay, but if I go back and try again, the delay just appears.

Update: simulator and physical device showed exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: in which method did you set title of second view controller?

Comment: Any code or image reference to make this clear?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko I set it in storyboard

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko Added screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, having the same problem